# PostgreSQL query not working in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, query, spatial-query

**Edit:** For further context, my table does have a unique id in the form of an integer. Through the database manager, the query executes successfully and I am able to load the query layer into QGIS. This same query however does not work when executed using the "PostgreSQL execute and load SQL" processing tool, which I intend to use for my model in the Graphical Modeler.

I am building a model in the QGIS Graphical Modeler which executes and loads PostgreSQL query. The query works perfectly fine when executed via the database manager, but when I try to run it through the graphical modeler it returns the two errors:

```
WARNING    Primary key field '"id"' for view/query not unique.
WARNING    PostgreSQL layer has no primary key.
```

This is the query I successfully executed via the Database Manager:

```sql
with mylot as
(select *
from lrs.nsw_lot l
where l.lotnumber in ('17','18')
and l.plannumber in ('24039'))
select b.*
from mylot inner join lrs.nsw_lot b on st_dwithin (mylot.geom, b.geom, 500)
where b.lotnumber not in ('17','18')
or b.plannumber not in ('24039')
```

And this is the query I'm attempting to execute through the graphical modeler:

```py
'with mylot as
(select *
from lrs.nsw_lot l
where l.lotnumber in (' || @lot_number || ')
and l.plannumber in (' || @dp_number || '))
select b.*
from mylot inner join lrs.nsw_lot b on st_dwithin (mylot.geom, b.geom,' || @radius || ')
where b.lotnumber not in (' ||  @lot_number  || ')
or b.plannumber not in (' || @dp_number  || ')'
```

These are my inputs when executing from the Graphical Modeler (shouldn't be relevant to my error, but just for extra context):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need a unique value to load the layer in QGIS. You could create a unique id with this SQL function :

```sql
SELECT row_number() over() as uniq_id
```

Comment: My apologies, my original statement may have been lacking further information. My table does have a unique id, and I am able to query and load my layer successfully via the database manager. However, when I use the same query in the Graphical Modeler, I receive the aforementioned errors.

Comment: Is your unique id an integer ?

Comment: Yes, the unique id is an integer.

Comment: Did you try to write the SQL function without a CTE expression, just replacing it by a nested query ?